# Assertion failure triggers a function

Tags: go, testing, assertion

Can I invoke a function when assertion fails?

E.g,

```
assert.True(t, condition) // invoke a function such as printing a map
```

Update: based on the suggestion, i wrote a small example. But does not seem to work.

assert.go

```
package main                                                                     

import _ "fmt"                                                                   

func compute() bool {                                                            
  return false                                                                   
}
```

assert_test.go

```
package main                                                                     

import (                                                                         
  "fmt"                                                                          
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"                                           
  "testing"                                                                      
)                                                                                

func pMap() {                                                                    
  amap := map[int]string{                                                        
    1: "hello1",                                                                 
    2: "hello2",                                                                 
  }                                                                              
  for i, _ := range amap {                                                       
    fmt.Println("map = ", i)                                                     
  }                                                                              
}                                                                                

func TestCompute(t *testing.T) {                                                 
  assert.True(t, compute(), pMap)                                                
}
```

$go test

```
--- FAIL: TestCompute (0.00s)
    assert_test.go:20: 
            Error Trace:    assert_test.go:20
            Error:          Should be true
            Test:           TestCompute
            Messages:       0x631a30
FAIL
exit status 1
```

Comment: for those who downvote, can you give a reason why this is downvoted? I dont see this as a trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

According to godoc, assert.True returns a bool, so you could wrap that in a conditional.
https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#True

```
passed := assert.True(t, compute()) // X will be a boolean true or false if the test passed.
```

You can use this to print maps /whatever like so:

```
if  passed {
     pMap()
} else {
     // test failed
}
```

Comment: I tried a small example. see above. Did not seem to work. Can you show me how to change it?

Comment: Additionally, what is conditional?

Comment: A conditional statement is an if statement. You could do something like this:

if assert.True(x) { //do stuff}

Comment: Why do you dismiss my answer without even testing it.  See my original post.

Comment: because i tested and it did not work? Can you show me a complete working example?

Comment: I added your initial example to my answer.